# Accessing keyof object from nested array of object JSON with pyspark

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have JSON file named Class.json and want to calculate all data with some condition.

Class.json

```
{
  "class": [
    {
      "class_id": "1",
      "data": {
        "lesson3": {
          "id": 3,
          "schedule": [
            {
              "schedule_id": "1",
              "schedule_date": "2017-07-11",
              "lesson_price": "USD 25",
              "status": "ONGOING"
            },
            {
              "schedule_id": "2",
              "schedule_date": "2016-09-24",
              "lesson_price": "USD 15",
              "status": "OPEN REGISTRATION"
            }
          ]
        },
        "lesson4": {
          "id": 4,
          "schedule": [
            {
              "schedule_id": "1",
              "schedule_date": "2016-12-17",
              "lesson_price": "USD 19",
              "status": "ONGOING"
            },
            {
              "schedule_id": "2",
              "schedule_date": "2015-11-12",
              "lesson_price": "USD 29",
              "status": "ONGOING"
            },
            {
              "schedule_id": "3",
              "schedule_date": "2015-11-10",
              "lesson_price": "USD 14",
              "status": "ON SCHEDULE"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "class_id": "2",
      "data": {
        "lesson1": {
          "id": 1,
          "schedule": [
            {
              "schedule_id": "1",
              "schedule_date": "2017-05-21",
              "lesson_price": "USD 50",
              "status": "CANCELLED"
            }
          ]
        },
        "lesson2": {
          "id": 2,
          "schedule": [
            {
              "schedule_id": "1",
              "schedule_date": "2017-06-04",
              "lesson_price": "USD10",
              "status": "FINISHED"
            },
            {
              "schedule_id": "5",
              "schedule_date": "2018-03-01",
              "lesson_price": "USD12",
              "status": "CLOSED"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried

```
df = spark.read.json("class.json", multiLine=True)
df.show()
```

and its shows:

```
+--------------------+
|               class|
+--------------------+
|[[1, [,, [3, [[US...|
+--------------------+
```

then for acceesing the array I've tried this one
`try = df.select("class").map(lambda s: s['data'])`

But got error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'`

or doing `df['class'][0]['data']` got `Column<b'class[0][data]'>`

Goal:

- count schedule that has the status "ONGOING" that has schedule date before 2017-01
- average lesson price before 2017-01

How to do it with pyspark?